# Blockchain implementation in IoT environment

Tags: blockchain

I'm new in blockchain implementation but I think that I understand how it works. The problem is that we want to implement blockchain in our IoT platform and all implementations and samples that I found are focus in financial environments (bitcoins).

Reading how it works I asume, that we will create a block for every message of every device. But I don't know if it is the best approach because we have a lot of vehicles (around 1000) that send us their position every 5 second (17280 messages by vehicle in a day). I'm worried about the volumen of the data. I'm not sure if it is that how we have to used it, or is better to create a block with a compilation of all information of every vehicle in a day.

I hope that you can understand my question because my English is not very good :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure blockchain is the right technology for this? Can you explain why you want to use blockchain, and why you think it is useful for this project?

Comment: @jnaczuk thanks for your answer. We are working in smart cities environments. Our customers are city halls and municipallities and they are asking us about using blockchain to grant the información we give them. So, my doubts are orientated on how to implement this in our IoT platform.